# How can I view my known spells?

Tags: elona-plus

I recently started playing Elona and I'm having trouble finding a list of my known spells and how much stock I have of each spells. I read the key list and magic sections of the Help Page (?), and took a look at the wiki but I didn't have much luck.

How do I open of a list of my known spells and the stock remaining for each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>V</kbd> is your quick key for reviewing (and also casting) spells, listed as 'Cast' in the help menu.

You can also find it using the <kbd>Z</kbd> quick menu, it's 'Spell', which is the top one on the first ring. It's also accessible if you accessed the Skills menu (which is <kbd>A</kbd>) and then hitting 7, 9, or Tab to switch which action menu you're looking at (this kind of tab switching for menus, you'd see in the top right of such menus what you can navigate around).